# Org-mode 9: unable to eval code-blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, eval, tangle

My Emacs config lives inside of a `.org` file from which I tangle source blocks to a `.el` file. I could evaluate source blocks with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>

Today I updated to org-mode version 9 from org elpa and now evaluating a source block like

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes
(setq org-export-coding-system 'utf-8)
#+END_SRC
```

with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> prints the following message

> Evaluation of this emacs-lisp code-blockis disabled.

In my `init.el` I have already defined the languages for org-babel:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
'org-babel-load-languages
'((emacs-lisp . t)
  (org . t)
  (sh . t)))
```

If I load the stock Emacs version of org-mode I can tangle with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> as expected.
I could not find any changes regarding this in the changelog for org-mode 9.

How to enable evaluation of code-blocks in org-mode 9?

Comment: Do you have the same issues, when you use `org-babel-execute-src-block` ?

Comment: Reinstall org-mode (delete org folder from `.emacs.d/elpa` first), that issue may have been solved already: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-11/msg00054.html

Comment: @bertfred results in same behaviour as <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>.

Comment: I had the same issue and had to hard-reinstall (something like this but I don't remember because I was frustrated and didn't take notes: uninstall, quit emacs, delete from elpa, start emacs, install from elpa, quit emacs, start emacs) )

Comment: I'm very sad to report that this problem seems to have returned. The following is from a fresh installation into a bare machine; evaluation of source blocks is disabled, and I don't see how to enable it. Org-babel seems to be dead. (emacs-version)
"GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1911))
 of 2016-09-17"
(org-version)
"9.0.5"

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think this problem is caused by the [change](http://orgmode.org/Changes.html#org184e052) of `org-babel-check-confirm-evaluate` from a macro to a function.  If you have `org-mode` (and thus the old macro) loaded when you compile the new code, it sees the old macro instead of the new function.

As others have pointed out uninstalling `org-mode` restarting Emacs (without loading `org-mode`) and reinstalling will fix the problem.  You can also delete the compiled `.elc` files and recompile with `byte-recompile-directory`.

Comment: Awesome I had the exact same Issue, and I couldn't understand why it wasnt working

Comment: Yes, this is a good explanation and solution. But I found the solution below, by @בנימן הגלילי much easier than uninstalling/reinstalling org-mode.

Answer (score 38):

To elaborate on @erikstokes:

```
rm ~/.emacs.d/elpa/ORGDIRNAME/*.elc
```

where `ORGDIRNAME` is the name of the core ogrmode directory. Restart emacs and  you can now run `org-babel` code blocks.

Comment: This worked for me with org-9.1.13.  It's quicker than re-installing.  _Note that the org directory name will likely differ_.

Comment: This worked for me on spacemacs

Answer (score 4):

for me uninstalling the org-plus-contrib package and reinstalling it solved it.

Comment: Reinstalling the same version or a later one?

Comment: remove current version and install latest from Melpa

Answer (score 3):

On Emacs 25.2 (9.0) and using `org-plus-contrib`:

- `org-babel-execute-src-block` gave me the same error as <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>
- deleting the `.emacs.d/elpa` folder and reinstalling did not fix it
- but `M-x package-delete [RET] org-plus-contrib` and reinstalling with `M-x package-install [RET] org-plus-contrib` *DID* fix it

Answer (score 0):

By default, Org enables only emacs-lisp ‘src’ code blocks for execution.

`org-babel-no-eval-on-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` variable can be used to remove code block execution from "C-c C-c" keybinding.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add following code in your `.emacs.d/init.el`.

```
;; ditaa
(require 'ob-ditaa)
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
(setq org-ditaa-jar-path
  "/path/to/ditaa-0_10.jar")
(org-babel-do-load-languages
  'org-babel-load-languages
  '((ditaa . t)
    (dot . t)))
```

Comment: I'd generally recommend *against* adding any kind of `require` to one's init file, because it slows down startup.

Comment: I did not know that until now. Thanks for the advice!