# Curly braces inside a body of the org-mode inline source block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I would like to use curly braces inside a body of the [org-mode inline source block](http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-of-code-blocks.html). Since the body itself is delimited with curly braces it seems impossible.

The problem occurs when additional pairs of curly braces are used inside the body. For instance the following LaTeX code

```
src_latex[:results raw]{$x=\frac{1}{2}$}
```

when executed (with C-c C-c) gets broken into

```
src_latex[:results raw]{$x=\frac{1} $x=\frac{1{2}$}
```

Of course this can be easily overcome with the classic (multiline) form of the source block, but the inline counterpart would be more convenient for me.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

I use Gnu Emacs 25.1.1 with Org-mode 8.3.4.

---

**UPDATE:**

It turns out (after short discussion on #org-mode IRC) that this issue does not apply to the Org Mode version 9.0.3 (at the time of writing this, 9.0.3 is the latest version available on Melpa). In fact, **after upgrading my Org Mode the problem disappears!**

Beware of [this issue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28441/org-mode-9-unable-to-eval-code-blocks) when updating to 9.X version!

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue. What version of emacs, `M-x version`, and org-mode,  `M-x org-version`, are you using? Also please provide and example that defines `par1`. Thanks!

Comment: @Melioratus You're right, thanks! I've updated my post according to your suggestions. The `:var x=par1` argument it is not needed to reproduce the issue, so for clarity I've decided to remove it.