# Org-babel 9 + Spacemacs: Unable to evaluate org-babel SRC Blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I followed every instruction I could here [Org-mode 9: unable to eval code-blocks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28441/org-mode-9-unable-to-eval-code-blocks), and I am unable to get org-mode and org-babel to evaluate any code blocks in any language. I am dead in the water and I am throwing myself on the mercy of this community for help.  I've spent the entire morning googling and reading and fenceposting and hacking with zero progress. All my org-mode files are dead!

Here is an MVE:

I stripped everything back to a fresh installation of [spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/), and here is the version info evaluated in the `*scratch*` buffer:

```
(emacs-version)
"GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1911))
 of 2016-09-17"

(org-version)
"9.0.5"

0.200.9@25.1.1 (spacemacs)
```

and added

```
  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '( (emacs-lisp  . t)
      ))
```

I also changed

```
'(safe-local-variable-values (quote ((org-confirm-babel-evaluate))))
```

into this

```
 '(safe-local-variable-values))
```

in an attempt to get anything at all to work.  It doesn't matter what the value of that expression is, I get the same negative results, with no clues about what to do to fix it.

I have copied the whole .spacemacs [here](https://gist.github.com/rebcabin/59548abc5436d9b2a9d7a6bdea139ab9).

I tried to run the emacs-lisp code block that looks like this

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output :exports both
    (princ (concat (format "Emacs version: %s\n" (emacs-version))
                   (format "org version: %s\n" (org-version))))

#+END_SRC
```

and made sure that the prevention codes are commented out

```
# By default I do not want that source code blocks are evaluated on export. Usually
# I want to evaluate them interactively and retain the original results.
# #+PROPERTY: header-args :eval never-export

* COMMENT babel settings
# Local variables:
# org-confirm-babel-evaluate: nil
# End:
```

I copied the entire org-mode file [here](https://gist.github.com/rebcabin/37d7c499a55e2bdb40960c54f529e6d4).

No matter what I do, I get

> ```
> Evaluation of this emacs-lisp code block is disabled.
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
cd .emacs.d/elpa/
# I suggest to run this without "delete" first.
find org* -name "*.elc" -delete
```

This will delete all compiled elisp files from org.
The problem is likely to be caused by conflicts between Org Mode that ships with Emacs and Org 9.

Restart Emacs afterwards and everything should work fine.

Comment: I would have sworn I did this at least 20 times. This times it worked!