# How to run C/C++ code in Org Babel?

Tags: org-babel, c++, c

I'm trying to execute C and/or C++ snippets in Org Babel.  For example, I want to be able to execute the following snippet with `C-c C-c`:

```
#+begin_src C
printf ("Hello World!");
#+end_src
```

[The documentation](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-C-new.html#sec-2) states that there are two installation steps: (1) having a C compiler available from `PATH`, and (2) having `C` added to the Org Babel load languages variable.

When I do this and I try to run the above code snippet, I get the following message:

```
Evaluation of this C code block is disabled.
```

The message suggests that there is something wrong with this particular code block (the use of the world *this*), but other code snippets result in the same message.

Was anybody able to run C and/or C++ code blocks in Org Babel?  Were more installation steps needed?

I'm using Org mode 9.1.2 and GNU Emacs 25.3.1.  Org Babel code block evaluation does work for other languages (e.g., SPARQL, SML, ELisp).

Comment: Are the source code block lines above the only text in the org file? Note that you can explicitly enable and disable a programming language in `org-babel-load-languages`. Double-check that `Activated` is really `on` for `C`! Is the value of `org-babel-C-compiler` meaningful on your system?

Comment: @Tobias Yes, the Org file only contains the hello world code block.  `(eval org-babel-C-compiler)` gives `gcc`.  I'm not sure what `Activated` is?  `(eval org-babel-load-languages)` gives `Invalid function: (C . t)`.

Comment: You cannot evaluate the value of `org-babel-load-language`. Nevertheless, the `(C . t)` in the error message of your attempt already shows that `C` is activated. Do you have `gcc` installed on your system?

Comment: @Tobias Yes, I'm using GCC 7.2.1.  I'm able to use GCC from within Emacs, `M-x compile` in C/C++ mode and such.

Comment: Strangely, I'm running into something similar, except it does evaluate in emacs 25.3 and does not evaluate in emacs 26 nightly. @WouterBeek which version of emacs are you running?

Comment: @amitp My `emacs-version` is "GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.19) of 2017-09-15".

Comment: Try `#+BEGIN_SRC C++`, it works for me (Emacs 25.1.1 on Mac).

Comment: @AhLeung Thanks for the suggestion, but I get the same behavior for C and C++ :(  Are more people experiencing this?  User `amitp` has observed the same behavior in at least one instance.  Maybe this should become a bug report?

Comment: I've got also emacs 25.3.1 under Cygwin. The emacs version is not so relevant here. More important is `M-x` `org-version` which is 9.0.9 on my box. Please, add the version numbers as info to your question.

Comment: See that orgmode-ticket: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7641. There they say that removing all the compiled files `*.elc` and byte-compiling the sources does the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28441/org-mode-9-unable-to-eval-code-blocks

Comment: I've added the Org mode version (9.1.2) and the GNU Emacs version (25.3.1) to the question.

Comment: I've also recompiled all `*.elc` files in `~/.emacs/elpa`, and I've uninstalled and then reinstalled org mode through the package manager (starting+closing Emacs in between these steps).  The issue is still the same.  Evaluation of other languages does work for me.  Only not for C/C++.

Comment: FWIW, it works fine for me: GNU Emacs 27.0.50, Org mode version 9.1.2.

Comment: I read the link Tobias had and … it had a comment from … me. How embarrassing. I reinstalled org and the problem disappeared for me. I don't know why it happened but my guess is I had a version mismatch. I'm not sure if the problem I had is the same thing @WouterBeek has.

Comment: Then there is a remote chance that emacs' own org-mode interferes... Try `M-x` `locate-library` `org` and `M-x` `locate-library` `ob-C`.

Comment: The fix was to do `rm ~/.emacs/elpa/org-20171009/*.elc` and then restart Emacs.  The overall issues seems to be an inconsistency between Org mode versions.  Very annoying that updating/installing Org does not automatically rebuild the `*.elc` files :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was basically given by @Tobias who shared the following links:

- https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7641
- [Org-mode 9: unable to eval code-blocks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28441/)

It is important to note that removing Org, restarting Emacs, and installing Org did *not* work for me.  And `C-0 M-x byte-recompile-directory RET ~/emacs.d/elpa/org-20171009` did *not* work either.

The only thing that worked for me was `rm ~/.emacs/elpa/org-20171009/*.elc` and then restart Emacs.

Comment: Strange. Frustrating. Glad you found something that worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `Evaluation of this C code block is disabled.` message is produced by `org-babel-check-evaluate` which in turn calls `org-babel-check-confirm-evaluate` to do the check. See the doc strings for these functions for details. The latter function checks for `:noeval` headers and `:eval` headers with values "no" or "never" or "no-export" or "never-export". In all these cases, the evaluation is disabled.

I would instrument `org-babel-check-confirm-evaluate` for [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html#Edebug), and step through it to find out why it is returning nil, and go from there.